# Process matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy

For example, there is a 4*2 matrix:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6],[7,8]]
```

I want to reshape it to 2*2 matrix and the value of it is the mean value of the original matrix, so the result will be:

```
[[2,3],[6,7]]
```

Is there any effective way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape the array to 3d and then take mean along the second axis:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6],[7,8]])
step = 2

a.reshape(-1, step, a.shape[-1]).mean(1)
#array([[ 2.,  3.],
#       [ 6.,  7.]])
```

Or use `np.add.reduceat` to add every two rows and then divide by 2:

```
step = 2
np.add.reduceat(a, np.arange(0,len(a),step))/step
#array([[ 2.,  3.],
#       [ 6.,  7.]])
```